# spring mvc - how to change json variable name

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm working on spring mvc and i need to send some json variable from action to the view. 
for this purpose, i use `ObjectMapper()` like below:

```
 modelAndView.addObject("myJsonVariable", mapper.writeValueAsString(myJsonVariable));
```

but i need to change name of some json variable. so, i found `@JsonRootName()` annotation and used it like this:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "searchoptions")
public class PageGridSearchOptions {

   ...
}
```

but not worked. configuration of mapper also not worked for me:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: what your myJsonVariable contains?

Comment: You probably want [`@JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation. Use it to define the field and its name.